# How to implement page sliding for Harmony OS?

Tags: java, huawei-mobile-services, harmonyos

How can I implement page sliding for GridView items in Harmony OS(JAVA)?
Here's a sample of my code.

```
public class GridView extends TableLayout {
    public GridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GridView(Context context, AttrSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
    }

    public GridView(Context context, AttrSet attrSet, String styleName) {
        super(context, attrSet, styleName);
    }

    void setAdapter(GridAdapter adapter, LongClickedListener longClickedListener) {
        removeAllComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getComponentList().size(); i++) {
            adapter.getComponentList().get(i).setLongClickedListener(longClickedListener);
            addComponent(adapter.getComponentList().get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a ScrollView outside the GridView and set the width and height of the ScrollView to a fixed value or `match_parent` to implement the sliding effect.

The following uses TableLayout inherited by GridView as an example:

```
<ScrollView
    ohos:height="match_parent"
    ohos:width="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        ohos:height="match_content"
        ohos:width="match_parent"
        ohos:background_element="#87CEEB"
        ohos:padding="8vp"
        >
     ...
     </<TableLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

If the problem persists, pls post the GridAdapter code for us to check.

Comment: this is not working ma'am

Comment: how come? could you pls post your full code for us to check? @JaY KuMaR

Comment: You can use the latest IDE to build a Grid project and compare it with the template code. I tried it on this side and it's sliding. See [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSC4H.jpg) and [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH2Kc.jpg).

Comment: @shirley I'm using the latest DevEco Studio IDE with grid temp. could you kindly post a sample java code which implements the page sliding. thanks

Comment: hi@Jamil, may i ask what is your test device? or have you used a simulator to try it?

Comment: @shirley I used the MatePad Pro virtual device. I just need to implement page sliding for my gridview items to other pages. If you can give a sample java code

Comment: It's weird, I can slide on both the real and virtual device, and the API version is set to 6.

Comment: @shirley a sample java code will be helpful cuz I've been stuck for days to implement this feature

Comment: hi@Jamil, could you pls leave your e-mail address so that i could send my project to you.

Comment: Yes, It has been sent to your email address on October 28th. Please check it.

Comment: @shrley I checked its not there...kindly send it again. thanks

Comment: i just send it again, did you get the mail?

Comment: @shrley no. this is my mail mahamajamil1@gmail.com